# How do I calculate the number of pixels necessary to render an arbitrary shape?

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, mobile

I have a problem where I want to approximate as closely as possible the area of an arbitrary user-drawn closed shape. I believe a good way to do this is to discover the number of pixels necessary to render the shape and divide them by the total number of active pixels on the device. Is there any way to discover the number of pixels active in presenting a graphic or to return the number of pixels currently presenting a specific color to the user on a mobile device?

Java, objective-c, or swift are all acceptable answers. This needs to run on a tablet!

Comment: "This needs to run on a tablet" - Run what?

Comment: Need to be able to return the area of the shape from a method call on a tablet. So I need to be able to count pixels in Java, Objective-C, or Swift. It needs to run on an iPad or an Android tablet.

Comment: Which method? What is your input?

Comment: The user will touch the screen to define the boundaries of an arbitrary shape. That shape will be colored to match the color of the outlining shape (if they selected red, the shape will be filled with red color) once they've completed a closed circuit and defined an enclosed area, I can capture any information generated by or necessary to complete the drawing process to be the input to my method. Any information I can access from a controller is fair game.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient, but in the absence of a better solution, this can be done by just checking each pixel. There is a method in Java to check whether a pixel is within the boundary of a shape, so this can be done.